# Can you store a string in a int in java?

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm reading a line of text from an external file, i have it set as a string so that the output will look like the same as it did inside the file I'm reading from. But i then have to do math and what not with the values i get from the file. so is there a way to convert it so that i can manipulate all the integer values?

Comment: You want to split your string so that each entry in the resulting array contains *just* a number. Then, just cast the string to an int.

Comment: What do the input lines look like? I'm guessing algebraic expressions like "42 * 12"? Or is it a list of numbers like "42, 43, 44"?

Comment: @Bob 10 gets you 1 this is yet another instance of "I need to evaluate math expressions in Java".

Answer (score 5):

```
String line = "123";
int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

Or if you have a CSV file:

```
String line = "123,234";
String[] numbers = line.split(",");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what i was asking

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use the `Integer.parseInt()` static method.

An example

```
String str_int = "10";
int a = Integer.parseInt(str_int);
// printing a which is integer
System.out.println("Java String to int: " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Integer.parseInt(String);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java programming, converting String to integer is easy. Though programmer who had worked in C++, might think converting String to Integer will be tricky, but its not the case. Java has wrapper classes for this purpose. We will use Integer wrapper class to convert String to int.

In your coding to convert  string to integer use :

Integer.parseInt(String);

Answer (score 0):

A string is one or more characters considered as a single value. Everything entered in a program, requested from the user, or displayed as a series of characters is primarily a string. To support strings, Java is equipped with the String class. To declare a variable that would hold a string, use the String data type.

Answer (score -1):

Java String class or Java String API is under package java.lang. String class provides various methods to play with strings for example: length(), charAt(int index), substring(int begin, int end), StringTokenizer (it’s a class), toUpperCase(), equals()…. and some others.

Comment: Yet another unattributed copy-paste, this time from http://www.java-forums.org/java-tutorials/2289-java-string.html. Please don't do this.